# how to fix fastlane error: Keystore file 'keystore.jks' not found for signing config 'externalOverride'.?

Tags: java, android, deployment, keystore, fastlane

Am new to fastlane, when I write the command for deploy the app to internal test its show me the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file '/Users/rooh/.gradle/daemon/5.1.1/keystore.jks' not found for signing config 'externalOverride'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

It seems that the error because the location of the keystore, I already put the keystore in app file of the project, I did that in other project and its work fine, but in this I dont know why its not working

I also tried to change the keystore location but still

this lane in fastfile:

```
desc "Deploy a new internal version to the Google Play Store"
lane :internal do
gradle(task: "clean")


gradle(
  task: "assemble",
  build_type: "Release",
  print_command: false,
  properties: {
    "android.injected.signing.store.file" => "keystore.jks",
    "android.injected.signing.store.password" => "*****",
    "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => "alias",
    "android.injected.signing.key.password" => "*****"
    }

)

changelog = prompt(
text: "Changelog: ",
multi_line_end_keyword: "END"
)


supply(
  track: "internal",
  apk: lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH].to_s
)
upload_to_play_store(track: "internal")
end
```

Comment: The gradle search the "android.injected.signing.store.file" => "keystore.jks", in app/keystore.jks

Comment: @jordiz yes I solve it by adding the hole path

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Rooh Al-mahaba says, I had to supply the **complete filepath** as the value for `"android.injected.signing.store.file"`.

Also, `~/` didn't work; I needed to explicitly spell out the full filepath.

Comment: using PWD works:
> ENV['PWD'] + "/app/keystore.jks",

Answer (score 7):

INFO: For other users:

You can create several ENV variables, this is useful for CI.

```
build_android_app(
      task: "assemble", 
      build_type: "Release", 
      flavor: "development",
      flags: "--stacktrace",
      print_command: false,
      properties:{
        "android.injected.signing.store.file" => ENV['KEYSTORE_PATH'],
        "android.injected.signing.store.password" => ENV['STORE_PASSWORD'],
        "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => ENV['KEY_ALIAS'],
        "android.injected.signing.key.password" => ENV['KEY_PASSWORD'],
        "org.gradle.java.home" => ENV['JAVA_HOME']
      })
```

Later you need to modify .bash_profile and add the ENV variables.

Answer (score 2):

**Flutter + Fastlane + GitHub Actions**

I had the same issue and, in my case, I was able to make it work by placing the keystore file in both `./android/fastlane/` and `./android/app/fastlane/` folders.

That is because I had my Fastlane configuration inside the `./android/fastlane/` folder, however, when you run **build_android_app** / **gradle** task it will try to fetch the keystore file in the `./android/app/` folder by default, and you **cannot** tell it to do otherwise unless you use an absolute path (not a good practice) since Fastlane tasks can't parse relative paths. Moreover, if I were to remove the keystore file from the `./android/fastlane/` folder, it would complain, even if it was present in `./android/app/fastlane/`.